# JPS command returns a list of multiple jps running

Tags: java

I am running jps command on Ubuntu and i can see a list of multiple jps processes are listed with all different process ids. What does this mean? Do I have multiple java process status tool running for different versions? Is it safe to kill other jps leaving one running. How this could have happened?

Thanks!

Comment: ever heard of multi-threading?

Comment: yes but here i see mutli-processing.